# Why the need of using await keyword for calling async method

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

```js
const tryToGetResult = async () => {
  const networkResult = await someNetworkRequest();
  console.log(networkResult); //Make sure networkResult is resolved to an object
  return networkResult;
}

const result = tryToGetResult();
```

`networkResult` is already an object and the flow has been taken care of by using `async/await`. But I don't understand why `const result = tryToGetResult()`, the `result` variable here is getting a `promise` instead?

I understand that the situation can be fixed by adding `await` as `const result = await tryToGetResult();`, I simply don't understand why the need of `await` here coz the flow of execution is clearly correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions marked as async always return a Promise

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

> An asynchronous function is a function which operates asynchronously via the event loop, using an implicit Promise to return its result.

Comment: Missed out this important bit of information, thank you very much!