# Can't seem to return a value, only a promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Im trying to write my first react native app so it doesnt do anything real complicated, just getting a feel for things. Right now it has a button which increases a text field by 1 when i press it and I also want the button to now display some text from another function which I have imported.

I have my main App.js and another file which i import into App.js which contains a function that returns a string value

```
import { myFunction } from './JSFunctions/functions.js'
```

myFunction runs fine on its own and will print its results to the console via console.log but when I add in the line

```
return output
```

all i get is

```
Promise { <pending> }
```

I realise I need to convert the promise by using `await` or `.then` somehow but ive been banging my head for hours on a desk trying to get it to work but I just get errors.

here are the functions

```
export async function myFunction(){
\\lots of other code here that has been removed 
    var i;
    var output;
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) { 
        output = DO STUFF AND CREATE A LONG STRING HERE
        console.log(output) //produces the correct output to console
    }
    return output;     
}
```

Here is the function in App.js

```
export default class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { 
      count: 0, 
      output_string: ''
    }
  }

  onPress = () => {
    this.setState({
      count: this.state.count+1,
      output_string: myFunction()
    })

  }  


  render(){ 
    const handlePress = () => false
    return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <View style = {styles.container}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={this.onPress}
        >
          <Text>
            My First Button
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <Text>Hello World! This is a text area.</Text>
        <Text>{ this.state.count !== 0 ? this.state.count: null}</Text>
        <Text>{this.state.output_string}</Text>
      </View>
    </React.Fragment>
    );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set state in a `then` callback chained to the `Promise` returned from `myFunction`:

```js
onPress = () => {
  myFunction().then(output => {
    this.setState({
      count: this.state.count+1,
      output_string: output
    });
  })
}
```

**Update**

You can also use `async / await` syntax:

```js
onPress = async () => {
  const output = await myFunction();
  this.setState({
    count: this.state.count+1,
    output_string: output
  });
}
```

**Update**

OP was asking if `count` and `output_string` can be updated independently.  Here is an example using `async / await`:

```js
onPress = async () => {
  this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });  // This happens immediately
  this.setState({
    output_string: await myFunction()
  });  // This happens as soon as the Promise returned by myFunction resolves
}
```

Comment: Thank you this worked. QQ, does the count:this.state.count+1 line need to be within the then callback? The number counter seems to be waiting for the output string to be calculated before it returns. Or is this unavoidable?

Comment: @zoonosis it depends on if you need both `count` and `output_string` to update at the same time.  If they can be updated independently from each other then yes, you could move setting `count` outside the callback.

Comment: Am I correct in saying that the only drawback with your async/await syntax answer is that both count and output_string will be calculated at the same time? Is there a way to use this method but still have count calculated seperately?

Comment: @zoonosis you can update `count` and `output_string` independently using either approach.  I've added an example that updates separately using `async / await`

Answer (score 2):

I've asked a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55133876/why-the-need-of-using-await-keyword-for-calling-async-method) recently, basically the reason is `myFunction` is an `async` function and hence it will only return `Promise`.

You have two options, either chain a `.then` or make your onPress an `async` method

```js
onPress = async () => {
    this.setState({
      count: this.state.count+1,
      output_string: await myFunction()
    })

  }
```

Comment: hmm, just seen this now. Does making the entire onPress function async have any benefits or is it usually overkill?

Comment: Well from my understanding, `async/await` keyword being introduced to replace `.then`. Reason is `.then` still takes in a form of nested callback which may lead to callback hell, as you can compare my answer with the accepted that, which one is easier to understand? But then of course this is rather subjective

Comment: `async / await` is just syntactic sugar over `Promises` and generators.  Essentially an `await` call more-or-less queues the rest of the function in a `then` callback chained to the `Promise` being `await`-ed (it's a bit more complicated, but that's an easy way to conceptualize what is happening).  So in the end both approaches behave very similarly and either one works just fine.

Comment: @brian-lives-outdoors: Thats exactly what I explained, and my point is using `async/await` improve readability which I also mentioned that it's quite subjective :)

Comment: @Isaac no worries, I added an `async` version to my answer and I'm upvoting yours for being the first to introduce the `async` approach

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `await` keyword from `myFunction`.

As it stands, you are saying that the function is asynchronous (hence the `async` keyword), which (in simple terms) means that it might not resolve a value immediately.

Because of this, a `promise` is returned, which (again, in simple terms) promises to return a value at some point in time.

I strongly suggest reading about async/await.

Edit: Or alternatively use @brian-lives-outdoors suggestion if you want the function to remain asynchronous.

Comment: Yes this function needs to be async as it does other stuff above the output which i removed